# ROS2 - Error while building packages with colcon ubuntu in wsl

Tags: ros2, build, colcon

I am trying to build my first package with colcon but I get the following errors while compiling the examples from ROS repository.
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 from WSL2.
If anyone knows why is this happening and how to solve this issue please help me.

```
sergio@Sergio:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --symlink-install
[2.272s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_minimal_service' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_minimal_client' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_service' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_executors' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_client' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher' is in: /opt/ros/iron
        'examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer' is in: /opt/ros/iron
```

If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:

```
--allow-overriding examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor examples_rclpy_executors examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server examples_rclpy_minimal_client examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher examples_rclpy_minimal_service examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber
```

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.

```
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_async_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_wait_set
[Processing: examples_rclcpp_async_client, examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor, examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client, examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server, examples_rclcpp_minimal_client, examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition, examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher, examples_rclcpp_minimal_service, examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber, examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer, examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor, examples_rclcpp_wait_set]
[Processing: examples_rclcpp_async_client, examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor, examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client, examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server, examples_rclcpp_minimal_client, examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition, examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher, examples_rclcpp_minimal_service, examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber, examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer, examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor, examples_rclcpp_wait_set]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/multithreaded_executor.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/multithreaded_executor.dir/multithreaded_executor.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/multithreaded_executor.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor [1min 30s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_client [2min 39s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_async_client [3min 1s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server [3min 31s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer [3min 40s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher [3min 42s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_service [3min 43s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client [3min 45s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor [3min 47s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition [3min 49s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber [3min 49s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_wait_set [3min 50s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [3min 52s]
  1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
  11 packages aborted: examples_rclcpp_async_client examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer examples_rclcpp_wait_set
  10 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_async_client examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor examples_rclcpp_wait_set
  10 packages not processed
```

Comment: Please edit your question to link to the specific tutorials that you're following. As well as describe what you've done up to this point to get here. In particular you appear to be doing an overlay which can be valid. Without knowing your context, what you're trying to do and what you want to do it's hard to give a good answer. You can avoid the overlay or suppress the warning. Both solutions are valid in different cases.